# SET NOCOUNT ON Still returns a "nn row(s) affected" message

Tags: sql-server, count, sql-server-2012, warnings

I have a simple stored procedure that simply selects data from a couple of tables and has only 1 input. The way I have set up my stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc_Name
(
 @input
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRY
    (
      SELECT statements go here
    )
     END TRY

     BEGIN CATCH

     END CATCH
END
```

Despite of putting the SET NOCOUNT ON, I still get "nn row(s) affected" message when I call the stored procedure.

I tried changing the location of the SET NOCOUNT ON, but that does not help either.

The other thing that I noticed was that my stored procedure returns a:

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

message.

Is this warning throwing off the SET NOCOUNT ON hint?

Comment: Are you also retrieving an execution plan when running the stored procedure? Are you inserting the results of the stored procedure call into a table? Is the procedure call really the only statement you are running? Does the procedure write to a table, and are there any triggers on that table? The message could be coming from a variety of other places. Try to describe your *whole* scenario.

Comment: Aaron, the procedure is a simple select statement that Left joins on 2 other tables. It does not write to any other table (so no insert statements in there). Its a pure SELECT statement with a where clause filtering on the input. I dont think I am retrieving any execution plan as this proc is called by a front end web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad folks. The proc name resembles too closely to another proc name. Turns out I was calling the wrong procedure and it was working fine. I changed my call and it works fine now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for your proc is incorrect.  It should be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc_Name
 @input
AS
BEGIN...
```

The parentheses are invalid around the parameters and you need the keyword AS.  I would correct this and make sure that your proc is actually compiling.
The warning means that you are aggregating a nullable column and it will return some value even if there are nulls.

Comment: Parentheses are not invalid, they're just optional. I assume the missing AS is just a transcription issue.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks - I was getting squiggles from the missing data type and I mistook the error.